# gmaven-plugin SAX parser error

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, gmaven-plugin

Today, I've encountered a strange problem with Groovy code that is run from Maven (using `gmaven-plugin`). I'm using Groovy only in Unit tests. All unit tests pass in Eclipse, however, I get errors on certain Unit tests when I'm running it with Maven.

The problematic Groovy code involves XML manipulation. It's a category method that adds an attribute to XML payload.

```
 class BaseTestCategoryMethods {
  private static XmlSlurper slurper = new XmlSlurper(false, false)
    public static String schemaVersion(String self, String version) {
    def root = slurper.parseText(self)
    root.@version = version
    return XmlUtil.serialize(root)
    }
 }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
  <error message="org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file." type="net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException">net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:418)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:214)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:50)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1611)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:129)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.BaseLRecTest$_closure3.doCall(BaseLRecTest.groovy:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1064)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:719)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.BaseLRecTest.invokeMethod(BaseLRecTest.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:346)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:719)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:346)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.LRecC4Test$_testFrequentFlyerAirlineCode_closure22_closure30.doCall(LRecC4Test.groovy:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1911)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1184)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.LRecC4Test$_testFrequentFlyerAirlineCode_closure22.doCall(LRecC4Test.groovy:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.LRecC4Test$_testFrequentFlyerAirlineCode_closure22.doCall(LRecC4Test.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.access$200(GroovyCategorySupport.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:202)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.use(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:324)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$613.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:155)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.mapper.xmlapproach.LRecC4Test.testFrequentFlyerAirlineCode(LRecC4Test.groovy:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:404)
    ... 109 more
```

And GMaven plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please help. I tried everything. Why does it work in Eclipse? I'm actually sure that the problem is not because of the category method.

Comment: maybe this could give you a clue http://www.danielschneller.com/2008/01/saxparseexception-1-1-premature-end-of.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find what was causing that faulty behaviour, however, I've managed to find a workaround that uses `XmlParser` instead of `XmlSlurper` and does not use `XmlUtil.serialize()` to prepare XML result:

```
 class BaseTestCategoryMethods {
    public static String schemaVersion(String self, String version) {
        def root = new XmlParser().parseText(self)
        root.attributes().put("version", version)
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
        def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(sw), "")
        printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
        printer.print(root);
        return sw.toString().readLines().join()
    }
 }
```

This works in Eclipse and from Maven command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not a *real* answer, but I struggled with GMaven myself for several months.  Then I switched to gradle and suddenly the clouds parted.  Great for building Java projects and using Groovy for testing etc.  GMaven seemed about dead to me earlier this year.  If you insist on using GMaven, I think I got the most out of examples of using Spock with Maven since the GMaven documentation seemed out of date to me.

Good luck!